# Deserializing JSON with a property in a nested object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

How can I easily deserialize this JSON to the OrderDto C# class? Is there a way to do this with attributes somehow?

JSON:

```
{
    "ExternalId": "123",
    "Customer": {
        "Name": "John Smith"
    }
    ...
}
```

C#:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I tried playing around with the JsonProperty attribute, but wasn't able to get it work. My ideas were to write an annotation like:

```
[JsonProperty("Customer/Name")]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

But it just doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thx! :)

Answer (score 10):

Your classes should look like this:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

A good idea in future would be to take some existing JSON and use http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: that link to json2csharp is very useful. Thank you!!!

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question meant deserializing nested objects without creating a new class.

Comment: Very useful comment, thanks. The question already had an answer and was therefore closed as a duplicate. This answer is to provide another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class that nests the rest of the properties like follows:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this is because Name is a nested property of the Customer object in the JSON data.

The `[JsonProperty("")]` code is generally used if the JSON name is different than the name you wish to give it in code i.e.

```
[JsonProperty("randomJsonName")]
public string ThisIsntTheSameAsTheJson { get; set; }
```

Comment: So, apart from introducing new classes, there is no other way? I was hoping that I didn't need to introduce new ones...

Comment: @bojank Not as far as I know. The C# side has to replicate how the data is represented in JSON. It might be possible to convert it to a key-value pair of strings or something but that is probably not preferred.

Comment: `"Customer": {"Name": "John Smith"}` is another object, there is no other way around than creating a new object for this.